# Print Management Console - All printers, drivers, ports missing

Tags: windows-server-2019, print-server

When running the Print Management console, nothing shows up in the drivers, ports, or printers. I can add new printers via the wizard. Then browsing to the UNC of the server I can see them. But the Print Management console shows nothing. Additionally, trying to connect to one of the printers ends up stuck on "Downloading the driver..." for at least 15 minutes. I gave up after that. Not sure if those are related issues.

*EDIT: after a reboot of my machine, I was able to add the printer with no issues. Still can't see anything in Print Management.

Given the ongoing printer nightmare situation, we have the "Allow Print Spooler to accept client connections" disabled on all machines except the print servers.

All other remote management functions seem to work just fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, new thing I noticed today. I was originally running Print Manager on a remote desktop machine we use for some admin tasks. When I run it on my computer, everything shows up fine. Also, on the remote desktop machine, if I right-click on the server in Print Manager and select properties, I can see the drivers in the Drivers tab. But they still don't show up when I select Drivers in the tree.

Comment: You may not be alone. I have a terminal server running 2016 for admin tasks. Removing and readding the print server to the Print Management console makes no difference. I cannot see the list of printers, drivers, etc. If I RDP to the print server and launch the print management console, everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

What i have seen now, due to the PrinterNightmare Vulnerability, we configured the GPO *Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Printers\Allow Print Spooler to accept client connections* for the Clients, which resulted in no Printers showing up in the Printer Management Console, because somehow the printserver does connect back to the client and thus this GPO setting must be allowed. Could it be this?

Comment: I'm not certain. But what seems odd is the same policy is applied to my workstation but Print Management Console shows everything fine on my workstation. Seems connected to the terminal server.

Comment: Maybe also have a look here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9957fe0e-797a-4e91-99d1-2886ba3e6575/print-management-on-remote-machine-shows-no-printers?forum=winserverprint 

or here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/printing/printers-list-blank-pmc

Another issue can be a problem with the DNS resolution of the workstation, where you want to open the print management console. Because the remote server needs so lookup the A record of the workstation.